# Confusion about working out with xib files and no storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xib

so I am kind of a beginner in ios development and I have some questions. I decided I was gonna start developing with no storyboards and so far so good, transitioning between VC make sense and everything. Recently I stumbled upon a problem that I honestly can't find an answer to, 
I have some view controllers and then at a point, I transition to another view controller in which I was hoping I could have an image as container for a tableviewcontroller i have in another xib file. After struggling too much on that I decided I was gonna skip that and simply open the tableviewcontroller as a new view but then it seems like tableviews don't open the same way as views, could someone explain to me how to do what I'm trying to do? I'm sorry if its a stupid question. I might be looking for the wrong question but I can't find the answer anywhere. TY

```
    @IBAction func moreInfoPressed(sender: MaterialButtonSettings) {
//        moreInfoVC = MoreInfoVC(nibName: "MoreInfoVC", bundle:  nil) 
//this is the one I was trying to do first which contained a view where I was hoping to open
 the TableVC... but oh well
//        self.presentViewController(moreInfoVC, animated:true, completion: nil)
        tableVC = TableVC(nibName: "TableVC", bundle: nil)
        self.presentedViewController(tableViewController, animated:true, completion: nil)
//doesnt seem to work either^
```

This is how im trying to bring up the TableView Controller

Comment: So you are trying to add a Viewcontroller as subview of another viewcontroller? Nopes, Only UIView can be added as subview of a ViewController.

Comment: You don't have a tableView, you have a tableViewController, that is a viewcontroller in itself as it is inherited from UIViewController class.

Comment: What you can do is you can present your tableViewController either modally or via navigation controller on more Info tapped event. The method to present VC modally is `self.presentViewController(yourVC(), animated: true, completion: nil)`, not self.presentedViewController

Comment: I appreciate it, in the end I ended up following this tutorial:
http://www.seemuapps.com/tutorial-custom-uitableview-cell